# Inner join query to get result for each weapon

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, inner-join

I have this query with an inner-join, however the WEAPON is unknown.
I want to get the best killer for each weapon. How can I do this with this query? I'm not really experienced with advanced queries.

```
    $q = $mysql->query("SELECT `killerID`
            , COUNT(`killerID`) AS tot_kills
            , MIN(`Username`) AS username
            FROM `kills`
            INNER JOIN `players`
            ON `players`.`id` = `kills`.`killerid`
            WHERE `killText` LIKE '%###WEAPON###%'
            GROUP BY `killerID`
            ORDER BY `tot_kills` DESC") or die($mysql->error);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the table names in the select clause since you are using `join`.
Try something like:

```
SELECT `kills`.`killerID`
            , COUNT(`kills`.`killerID`) AS tot_kills
            , MIN(`players`.`Username`) AS username
            FROM `kills`
            INNER JOIN `players`
            ON `players`.`id` = `kills`.`killerid`
            WHERE `kills`.`killText` LIKE '%###WEAPON###%'
            GROUP BY `kills`.`killerID`
            ORDER BY `kills`.`tot_kills` DESC
```

Comment: This is only needed if the two tables share a column with the same name, and only if that column name is used in your query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should group by weapon and not killer id, as you want number of `killerID` by `weapon`.

Note that you don't need all these backticks.  Backticks are required only if your table name or coluumn name in the query is one of the reserved words.

```
SELECT killerID
        , COUNT(killerID) AS tot_kills
        , MIN(Username) AS username
FROM kills
INNER JOIN players
  ON players.id = kills.killerid
WHERE killText LIKE '%###WEAPON###%'
GROUP BY kills.killText
ORDER BY tot_kills DESC
```